# How can you make the copyright text in a Google Map wrap when the map is small?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, internet-explorer-8

When you embed a Google Map on a web page, copyright text is included on the map.

If you embed a map with a small width, the copyright text extends outside of the `<div>`, instead of wrapping onto two lines within it.

This is the HTML that Google Maps inserts for the copyright text:

```
<div style="-moz-user-select: none; z-index: 0; position: absolute; right: 3px; bottom: 2px; color: black; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: right;" dir="ltr">
    <span></span>
    <span>Map data &copy;2010  LeadDog Consulting, Europa Technologies - </span>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/help/terms_maps.html" target="_blank" class="gmnoprint terms-of-use-link" style="color: rgb(119, 119, 204);">Terms of Use</a>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

I’ve tried using jQuery to select this HTML based on its contents (using `:contains()`) and style it differently, but none of the styles are applied in IE 8. They’re applied fine in IE 7 and Firefox.

```
$('.map_placeholder div:contains("Map data ")').css({'white-space': 'normal', 'margin-left': '70px', 'width': '210px', 'border-top': 'solid 10px #c00'});
```

- Any idea what’s up with IE 8?
- Do you know other methods to achieve the same result?

Comment: Add the code and styling you apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div span { white-space: normal;}
```

Comment: Ah yes: that’s the style I’m trying to apply in IE 8, but none of the styles seem to be taking effect.

Comment: Doh, sorry: I was still thinking in JavaScript terms. Just sticking this in the stylesheet, which is what you were saying, will do it. I’ve made the rule a bit more specific to the map, but otherwise this is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set `overflow:hidden` on the outer `div` and nothing will extend outside its box.

I'd be careful with removing/styling the copyright text though, since it is likely a breach of Google's TOS.

Comment: Using the white-space: normal approach, the whole text will (likely, depending on size) be visible within the map. However, I agree with DisgruntledGoat, read the TOS.

Comment: Yeah, I’m definitely looking for the copyright text to be visible — even aside from the TOS issues, it’d still look bad if it was clipped.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this, and it works. Overwrite the inline css with the following:

```
div[style]{
 font-size: inherit !important;
 white-space: inherit !important;
}


span[style]{
 white-space: inherit !important;
}

a[style]{
 color: inherit !important;
}

span { white-space: normal; }
```

Comment: Ah yes: turns out just the last line will do it in this case.